# Intellij Window open Minimized

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

When Opening up a new project in Intellij the window opens up extremely minimized and almost impossible to see. Is there a properly to set the default window size when opening.

My Setup 
Mac OSX El Capitan 
Intellij 2015 - 16.3.4 (I have experienced this in all of these versions)

See image below for how small the Window opens

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you start IDE will all the defaults after removing [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)? It could be that some configuration is corrupted.

Answer (score 7):

You can maximize and then choose from top menu - `Window > Store Current Layout as Default`. Generally, it remembers the size of the Window before closing.